# Numerical Scheme for Heat flow between two materials with different conductive properties.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics, heat-equation, finite-differences

I am trying to write a simulation in MATLAB for a $1D$ heat flow problem in which there are two materials in contact with each other but with different thermal properties. The results are unstable so I am trying to see what I'm doing wrong. Here is my problem
$$
\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t} = k_s\dfrac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}, -1<x<0
$$
$$
\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t} = k_i\dfrac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}, 0<x<1
$$
with boundary conditions 
$$
T(0^-, t) = T(0^+, t)
$$
$$
\lambda_sT_x(0^-, t) = \lambda_iT_x(0^+, t)
$$
$$
T(-1, t) = 1, T(1, t) =0
$$

The numerical schemes I used for the interior points were normal implicit finite difference methods with $d_s = k_s \Delta t/\Delta x^2$ and $d_i = k_i \Delta t/\Delta x^2$:

$$
-d_sT_{j+1} ^{n+1} + (2d_s+1)T^{n+1}_{j} - -d_sT_{j-1}^{n+1} = T^n_j 
$$
for $j < 0$ and 
$$
-d_iT_{j+1} ^{n+1} + (2d_i+1)T^{n+1}_{j} - -d_iT_{j-1}^{n+1} = T^n_j 
$$

for $j > 0$. Whenever we have $j+1$ or $j-1$ equal to $0$, we use the average of $ d_s, d_i$ to represent the transfer coefficient at the connection point. To satisfy the continuity equation $T(0^-, t) = T(0^+, t)$. I just used the same point for both finite difference stencils. However, I tried implementing the continuity of flux boundary condition with the following logic

$$
\lambda_sT_x(0^-, t) = \lambda_iT_x(0^+, t) \approx \lambda_s \dfrac{T^{n+1}_{0} - T^{n+1}_{-1}}{\Delta x} = \lambda_i \dfrac{T^{n+1}_{1} - T^{n+1}_0}{\Delta x} \implies
$$
$$
-\lambda_i T^{n+1}_1 + (\lambda_s + \lambda_i) T^{n+1}_0 - \lambda_s T^{n+1}_{-1} = 0
$$

However, in the case I considered where $\lambda_i = \lambda_s$, this scheme became unstable and exploded. I think my math is wrong about the continuity of flux, or just using the average of the two coefficients as the transfer at $0$. Does anyone have any insight on how to implement this?

Comment: When you take $\lambda_i=\lambda_s$, do you also set $k_i=k_s$? Another question would be on how you handle the transfer at the joint. Your approach is different than what mine would be. Probably, you should explain your method a little bit more.

Comment: Currently I have been just using $k_s = \lambda_s$ and $k_i = \lambda_i$, although the paper I am replicating used different names so I felt it might be good to distinguish that here. What do you mean by how I handle transfer at the joint?

Comment: Basically, the continuity condition. I would have taken $_1T$ and $_2T$ as separate unknowns and set $_1T^{n+1}_0 - _2T^{n+1}_0 = 0$. But you are doing something different and I do not exactly understand what you are doing.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the paper you're trying to replicate?